# Как растянуть вложенный тег <a> с учетом родительского padding

Tags: html, css

```css
#parent {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#inner {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    border: 1px dotted green;
    /*Надо растянуть элемент с учетом padding, то есть чтобы ширина была 110px*/
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <a id="inner">TextThatShould</a>
</div>
```

Comment: а зачем так делать?

Comment: Чтобы добавить сниппет, нажмите эту кнопку на картинке: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPQvE.png

Comment: @HELO, Чтобы внешний `div` по клику был как ссылка

Comment: @VenZe, спасибо

Comment: подробнее напишите для чего вы так делаете?

Comment: @HELO, делаю своё навигационное меню, нужны кнопки большие. Я ничего другого путного не придумал, кроме как растянуть <a> по всему размеру <div>

Comment: мне кажется, правильнее давать паддинг тегу <a>, если цель расширить кликабельную область

Comment: @Herrgott не перепутали ли вы свойство `border` и `background` в примере?

Comment: @VenZell, перепутал точно, спасибо

Comment: lexxl, тогда `background` родителя не растянется, текст будет вылезать за рамки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вам подойдёт следующий вариант:

```css
#parent {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#inner {
    display: block;
    height: 100%; 
    border: 1px dotted green;
    /*Надо растянуть элемент с учетом padding, то есть чтобы ширина была 110px*/
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <a id="inner" href="#">TextThatShould</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему как я ожидал, область текста не вылезает за размеры родителя?

Comment: @Herrgott а с чего это ребенок должен вылезать за пределы родителя, тем более когда родитель ячейка)

Comment: @василий, просто я часто встречался с таким поведением и много раз забрасывал изучение web дизайна. Видимо все-таки `display: table-cell` делает то, что надо

Comment: @василий, вот например у меня теперь такая проблема появилась. <ul> вылезает за пределы родительского <div>

Comment: @Herrgott пример в студию в отдельный вопрос

Comment: @Herrgott `display` тут решает все. Он отвечает, как раз таки, за поведение элемента на странице. А на самом деле, более правильно, чтобы именно наследник растягивал родителя (в случаях с меню, или пунктами)